# How to update $scope variable value in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have a `$scope` variable in my controller. Initially it will load a value.

My requirement is that I want to update `$scope` variable value when button click.

Please let me know how can i achieve this.I am newbie to Angular.

```
var userName='UserName';

   tepTableModule.controller('tepTableCtrl',function($scope,Service,$filter) {
       $scope.searchText=userName;
       $scope.refreshData = function() {

//when refreshData function called i want to update $scope.searchText value   to new value.
     $scope.tableData.data = $filter('filter')(tepJobData, $scope.searchText, undefined);
       };
    }
```

Comment: paste your html snippet as well

Comment: does `$scope.searchText = newValue;` not work?

Comment: @ Claies yes it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make use of the `ng-click` directive.

Its a directive that will execute a method in your controller when the user clicks on the element. It us not limited to just methods, it will evaluate an angular expression, so can be used to set flags on elements, increment counters etc.

So

```
<!--Execute Method-->
<button ng-click="refreshData()">Refresh</button>
<!--toggle Scope property isDisabled-->
<button ng-click="isDisabled = !isDisabled">toggle disabled</button>
<!--increment count by 1-->
<button ng-click="count += 1">Add 1</button>
```

With controller as

```
$scope.refreshData = function () {
    //epic refreshes
}
$scope.isDisabled = false;
$scope.count = 0;
```

docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick

Answer (score 2):

You can make function and call it on ng-click:

on Controller:

```
$scope.doSomething = function (){
//do something
}
```

On View:

```
<button ng-click="doSomething()">Click Me</button>
```

That's it, good luck

Comment: Thats not entirely correct. You have to define your method of your `$scope` or `this` if using `controller as`. This code as it stands won't execute anything as your method is just defined as a normal function.

Comment: yes, you are right and that what I meant, anyways, thanks and I will update my answer.